# Which directed graphs correspond to "algebraic" diagrams?

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory

Any diagram for which the question of commutativity make sence is a directed graph, but not any directed graph make the question meaningful.
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    A @>>> B @. A @>>> B\\
    @AAA @VVV @VVV @AAA\\
    C @<<< D @. C @<<< D
    \end{CD}
The squares above make no sence according to commutativity, but below are some qriteria listed that seems to be necessary for an "algebraic graph".

1. Any vertex must be associated to at least two edges.
2. If two different edges leads from (to) the same vertex, they are parts of two different ways that leads to (from) a common vertex.
3. There must be at least one vertex with two different edges pointing to it.
4. No loops.

Is this a complete list? Is it correct? Is there a name for this kind of graphs?

Comment: Doesn't your second graph satisfy all three points?

Comment: @A.P. No, not point 2, which is a double qriteria:  the main case and the bracket case.

Comment: A directed graph is a commutative diagram if and only if every undirected cycle consists of two directed paths with the same initial vertex and the same final vertex.

Comment: @Batominovski: It seems to be correct. And then the answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1325051/category-theory-enough-that-polygonal-diagrams-commute become trivial.

Comment: I would suggest that my reply above be put as a definition of "combinatorial commutative diagrams."  Then, an "algebraic commutative diagram" in a category $C$ would be a combinatorial commutative diagram whose vertices are labelled by objects in $C$ and whose arc starting from a vertex with label $a\in C$ and ending in a vertex with label $b\in C$ is labelled by a morphism in $\text{Hom}_C(a,b)$ such that the commutativity of morphisms in every undirected cycle is satisfied.  (The reason I say "labels" is that two distinct vertices may actually represent the same object.)

Comment: @Batominovski: I think there should be a supplement to your straight forward definition, that every vertex should be a part of a cycle.

Comment: True.  Forgot about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, a diagram in $\mathcal{C}$ is *not* the same thing as a directed graph. A $\Gamma$-shaped diagram in $\mathcal{C}$ is a morphism of graphs $\Gamma\longrightarrow U(\mathcal{C})$, where $U(\mathcal{C})$ denotes the underlying directed graph of $\mathcal{C}$ ${}^{1)}$.

Secondly, it makes sense to talk about commutativity for all kinds of graphs. It is just the usual notion: A diagram is commutative, if for all sequences $$A=V_1\xrightarrow{f_1}V_2\longrightarrow\dots\longrightarrow V_{n}\xrightarrow{f_{n}}V_{n+1}=B$$ and
$$A=W_1\xrightarrow{g_1}W_2\longrightarrow\dots\longrightarrow W_{m}\xrightarrow{g_{m}}W_{m+1}=B$$
we have $g_{m}\circ\dots\circ g_1=f_{n}\circ\dots\circ f_1$.

Note as one subtility here: The case $n=0$ is allowed${}^{2)}$! What does that mean? It means that we have an empty composition, i.e. the identity. This implies, that whenever a sequence ends at the point it started at, composition is the identity. In particular, all loops are the identity.

For example, your first diagram is commutative, if and only if whenever walking round the diagram, one ends up with the identity. The diagramm $A\leftrightarrows B$ is commutative if and only if the arrows are inverse isomorphisms. Your second diagram is always commutative.

${}^{1)}$ Via the free-forgetful adjunction between graphs and categories, this is the same thing as a functor $F(\Gamma)\longrightarrow\mathcal{C}$. One can show that limits and colimits of a diagram as morphism of graphs are the same thing as limits and colimits of the associated functors, which justifies the common practice of considering limits of *functors*. Note however, that one *defines* the limit of a functor $\mathcal{J}\longrightarrow\mathcal{C}$ as the limit of the underlying morphism $U(\mathcal{J})\longrightarrow U(\mathcal{C})$, so I think it's more natural to think of diagrams as morphisms of graphs.

${}^{2)}$ This is a more monadic point of view. It says that it is more natural to consider $n$-fold composition as a basic concept, not as a derived one, inductively defined using $2$-fold composition, associativity and treating $n=0$ as a special case.

Comment: That is a problem with category theory: it steals definitions... :)

Comment: @Jakob Werner, I was aware of the case $n=0$ as you stated when I typed down my comment.  However, I discussed with somebody in the past and they stated that this type of diagrams shouldn't be included, whence when I replied, I declared that there must be "two direct paths" to avoid the dispute.  I do agree with you though.  If we want to include the $n=0$ case, we would have to modify my definition to say: "every undirected cycle consists of at most two directed, possibly closed, paths."

Comment: I remember now why some people want to ignore directed closed paths in a commutative diagram.  Let's take this example: $f:A\to B$, $g:B\to C$, and $h:C\to A$.  It is possible to have $h\circ g\circ f=\text{id}_A$, but $f\circ h\circ g \neq \text{id}_B$ or $g\circ f\circ h \neq \text{id}_C$.  Hence, it is unclear where the starting point should be.

Comment: An example is in the category of abelian groups with $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $B=C=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$.  We define $f$ to be the injection $a\mapsto (a,0)$, $g$ the identity, and $h$ the projection $(a,b)\mapsto a$.  Hence, $h\circ g\circ f=\text{id}_A$, $f\circ h\circ g\neq\text{id}_B$, and $g\circ f\circ h\neq \text{id}_C$.  Hence, we have this pathology with ambiguity of directed closed paths.

Comment: @Batominovski but of course you just require all starting points to satisfy the condition.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is how we should define a commutative diagram.  There are too many different opinions.  Some people like me would want a clear starting point if there is a directed closed path, some like Jakob Werner would prefer arbitrary starting points, and some like Lehs don't want any directed closed paths altogether.  The best resolution I see is to exclude all directed closed paths.