# A question about combinatorial commutative diagrams.

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory, definition

In the comments of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1377039/which-directed-graphs-correspond-to-algebraic-diagrams) the directed graphs that can appear as commutative diagrams are axiomatized:

> A graph is a *combinatorial commutative diagram* iff it's nonempty and such that any vertex is a part of a finite undirected cycle and such that any undirected cycle consists of two directed paths with the same start and end vertices.

Can it be proved for such graphs that:

> Given two different edges directed from the same vertex, there are directed paths including these edges leading to a common vertex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessary, consider the directed graph on $A,B,C,B',C'$ with arcs $A\to B$, $B\to C$, $A\to C$, $A\to B'$, $B'\to C'$, and $A\to C'$.  This directed graph is a counterexample to your claim since $A\to B$ and $A\to B'$ do not lead to a common vertex.

P.S. *Combinatoric* is not a word, *combinatorial* is.

Comment: But $B^\prime$ is not a part of a cycle...

Comment: Sorry, typo.  Look at the reply again.

Comment: But $A\rightarrow C\leftarrow B\rightarrow C^\prime\leftarrow B^\prime\leftarrow A$ is an undirected cycle that doesn't meet the conditions since there are no directed paths with common vertices.

Comment: Look again: $B\to C'$ is not there anymore.  It was my typo.